# Webview isn't showing the page

Tags: javascript, java, android, webview

Yesterday I began a project for my father to have all his web radio's on an app using the embed code that radionomy provides.

I think the code is well formed but when I execute the application, the app just shows a blank page.

Main activity code:

```
import android.annotation.TargetApi;
import android.os.Build;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.webkit.WebResourceRequest;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;

public class CalsicaActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_calsica);
        WebView clasica = new WebView(this);
        clasica.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        setContentView(clasica);
        clasica.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
            @Override
            @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.N)
            public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView clasicav, WebResourceRequest request) {
                clasicav.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/index.html");
                return false;
            }
            @Override
            @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
            public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView clasicav, String url) {
                clasicav.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/index.html"); 
                return false;
            }
        });
        //clasica.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/index.html");
    }
}
```

Html code:

```
<html>
<head><script>
    (function (win, doc, script, source, objectName) {
        (win.RadionomyPlayerObject = win.RadionomyPlayerObject || []).push(objectName);
        win[objectName] = win[objectName] || function (k, v) {
            (win[objectName].parameters = win[objectName].parameters || { src: source, version: '1.1' })[k] = v;
        };
        var js, rjs = doc.getElementsByTagName(script)[0];
        js = doc.createElement(script);
        js.async = 1;
        js.src = source;
        rjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, rjs);
    }(window, document, 'script', 'https://www.radionomy.com/js/radionomy.player.js', 'radplayer'));
    radplayer('url', 'bravo-clasic');
    radplayer('type', 'medium');
    radplayer('autoplay', '1');
    radplayer('volume', '50');    
    radplayer('color1', '#000000');
    radplayer('color2', '#ffffff');
</script></head>
<body>
    <div class="radionomy-player"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

I already added `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>` on the android manifest.

I have no idea of what I could've done wrong, I'd appreciate some help.

Comment: did you add **INTERNET** permission in manifest file

Comment: @NileshRathod Yup

Comment: why your are doing **setContentView** two times

Comment: @NileshRathod Already erased it and keeps without working

Comment: check my below ans

Comment: @InsaneDarkness is the same html working fine in laptop?

Comment: @Ajay_Reddy Yes it's

Answer (score 0):

try this first load url in to your `web view` that perform `setContentView`

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);


        WebView clasica = new WebView(this);
        clasica.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        clasica.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/index.html");

        setContentView(clasica);


        //clasica.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/index.html");
    }
```

Comment: Now it pop's up net:ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS

Comment: Same as before :c

Answer (score 0):

Well below code will be called only when load some url ***(by loadUrl() method )***. Please check method signature it says should override.

By setting webview client you are  just stating that what should happen  during load time. But the things that your trying to make happen should start first. Am i making any sense ?

```
clasica.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
        @Override
        @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.N)
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView clasicav, WebResourceRequest request) {
            clasicav.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/index.html");
            return false;
        }
        @Override
        @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView clasicav, String url) {
            clasicav.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/index.html"); 
            return false;
        }
    });
```

Solution :

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
   // setContentView(R.layout.activity_calsica);
    WebView clasica = new WebView(this);
    clasica.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
  // remove below code you dont need this
   /* clasica.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
        @Override
        @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.N)
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView clasicav, WebResourceRequest request) {
            clasicav.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/index.html");
            return false;
        }
        @Override
        @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView clasicav, String url) {
            clasicav.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/index.html"); 
            return false;
        }
    });*/
 // you need this line   
 clasica.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/index.html");
 setContentView(clasica);
}
```

Comment: I'm not really understanding you xD

Comment: Now it's just another blank page

Comment: check updates ans. if still wont then try load the html from sdcard first, check its behaviour if it loads then it load in web view

Answer (score 0):

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    WebView clasica = new WebView(this);
    clasica.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/index.html");
    setContentView(clasica);
}
```

Comment: Shows net:ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS